# Simple jQuery super slow on firefox, IE, super fast on Chrome

Tags: jquery

Brand new to jQuery. Have implemented the function below into a page I am developing, and what I thought was relatively simple jQuery is proving problematic.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var leftnav = $("#leftnav ul li");

    leftnav.hover(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown();

    },function(){
                $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });

});
```

Basically, this runs brilliantly in Chrome and Opera - lovely, smooth, fast. In Firefox and IE8 it runs like a dog - jerky, slow, like it's wearing a suit of mud. As I said I am brand new to jQuery - this is the first time I have tried to implement any into a web page. I have tried the same using mouseenter and mouseleave, but there is little difference.

I would have expected problems with IE8, but bit gutted that firefox is giving me issues as I have always sworn by it. Do I just have to accept this and make consessions?

Thanks

EDIT : Ok, I've managed to speed things up a bit. Whilst still not grease lightning Chrome performance, IE8 and firefox are now what I would call acceptable. I got some tips from this excellent page - http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

I simply made my selector var more specific by giving '#leftnav ul' it's own ID in my markup- #list, and then referencing that in my jQuery code. So,

```
var leftnav = $("#leftnav ul li");
```

becomes:

```
var leftnavUl = $("#list li");
```

From what I gather this allows jQuery to hone in more efficiently on the element in question.

Using console.time in firebug, I have noticed the speed increase from ~15ms to ~10ms for each slideDown operation, just by being more specific in my selectors.

Like I say, not as qucik as Chrome still, but getting better!

Answer (score 0):

If its not throwing errors or glitching, then theres probably not much you can do.

The code doesn't look like it has any massive loops or anything that would cause it to lag, perhapse it's simply how the browsers handel jQuery.

Why don't you use:

$("#leftnav ul li ul").hover(...ect...)

That way you can cut out the 'children' call and the var.
That is unless your using them for something else.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately I have already tried every combination of referencing the element directly, using or not using the var and using or not using the children call, and it has made no difference. Wondering if it might be something to do with my DOM structuring... Any jQuery experts have any suggestions on that front?

Comment: can you post a link to a live demo?